# Haskell - put function on pair

Tags: haskell

I have a following `State` monad:

```
type S = (M.Map String Integer, [String])
```

Now, I have a function:

```
rTD :: [String] -> ReaderT Env (StateT S (ErrorT String IO)) 
rTD (s, _) <- get
-- (1) how to here use put function to modify one element of pair my Store ?
```

(1) how to here use put function to modify one element of pair my Store ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general case:

```
rTD xs = do
    (m, ys) <- get
    let m' = ...
    let ys' = ...
    put (m', ys')
```

The gets/modify case:

```
rTD xs = do
    m <- gets fst
    let m' = ...
    modify (\s -> (m', snd s))
```

With lens:

```
rTD xs = do
    _1 %= Map.insert "key" 777
    _2 %= ("foo":)
```